# Algorithm for string processing

Tags: string, algorithm, search

I am looking for a algorithm for string processing, I have searched for it but couldn't find a algorithm that meets my requirements. I will explain what the algorithm should do with an example.

There are two sets of word sets defined as shown below:

```
**Main_Words**: swimming, driving, playing
**Words_in_front**: I am, I enjoy, I love, I am going to go
```

The program will search through a huge set of words as soon it finds a word that is defined in **Main_Words** it will check the words in front of that Word to see if it has any matching words defined in **Words_in_front**.

i.e If the program encounters the word "Swimming" it has to check if the words in front of the word "Swimming" are one of these: I am, I enjoy, I love, I am going to go.

Are there any algorithms that can do this?

Comment: It depends ... what approach have you already tried? What language would you use to implement this?

Comment: I want to implement this using java. I know i can find the words defined in the main_words, i am not sure of the logic that i should use to check the words in front.

Comment: Is your "huge set of words" that you're searching through a long string of text, or literally a set? Also, how long might the longest `words_in_front` member be?

Comment: From how you described the problem, I'd say you could simply use `if` and `.equals()`. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Noyo Its a text file filled with words

Comment: @Sindu_, can we make any assumptions about the relative sizes of the two sets, `main_words` and `words_in_front`? Is there any reason you're searching for the "main words" first and not the prefixes (that is, do we know that the main words will be more/less common than the prefixes?)? Also, are you reading the file as a stream, or line by line, or all-at-once, or what?

Comment: @Noyo main_words will contain around ten words and words_in_front will contain up to fifty words altogether. Yes, as per the words in the text file the words_in_front appear more commonly than main_words. I am reading the file as a stream

Comment: @Sindu_, in this case, you can definitely benefit from doing something like what I specify in my answer below (i.e., keep track of the last N words & check). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way to do this would be to just do a linear scan through the text, always keeping track of the last N+1 words (or characters) you see, where N is the number of words (or characters) in the longest phrase contained in your `words_in_front` collection. When you have a "main word", you can just check whether the sequence of N words/characters before it ends with any of the prefixes you have.

This would be a bit faster if you transformed your `words_in_front` set into a nicer data structure, such as a hashmap (perhaps keyed by *last* letter in the phrase..) or a prefix/suffix tree of some sort, so you wouldn't have to do an `.endsWith` over every single member of the set of prefixes each time you have a matching "main word." As was stated in another answer, there is much room for optimization and a few other possible implementations, but there's a start.

Answer (score 1):

Create a map/dictionary/hash/associative array (whatever is defined in your language) with key in **Main_Words** and **Words_in_front** are the linked list attached to the entry pointed by the key. Whenever you encounter a word matching a key, go to the table and see if in the attached list there are words that match what you have in front.

That's the basic idea, it can be optimized for both speed and space.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) along these lines:

```
I (am|enjoy|love|am going to go) (swimming|driving|playing)
```